# Im having issues adding multiple parent nodes to a tree view

Tags: c#, treeview

When i want to add a parent node, the first one i add works,
[Parent Node 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy2Pn.png)
but when i want to add another parent with the same features this happens:
[Parent Node 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dscEy.png)

Heres My Code:

public void add()
        {

```
        TreeView t = new TreeView();
        t = treeView1;
        names.Add(textBox1.Text);
        passwords.Add(textBox2.Text);
        emails.Add(textBox3.Text);
        websites.Add(textBox4.Text);

        string addedname = textBox1.Text;
        string addedpass = textBox2.Text;
        string addedemail = textBox3.Text;
        string addedwebsite = textBox4.Text;
        string nodename = textBox5.Text;
        int treecount = 0;

        removewhat = nodename;

        t.Nodes.Add(nodename);
        t.Nodes[treecount].Nodes.Add($"Username: {addedname?? "Empty"}");
        t.Nodes[treecount].Nodes.Add($"Password: {addedpass?? "Empty"}");
        t.Nodes[treecount].Nodes.Add($"Email: {addedemail?? "Empty"}");
        t.Nodes[treecount].Nodes.Add($"Website: {addedwebsite ?? "Empty"}");

        treecount += 1;

        removewhat = null;
        nodename = null;
        addedname = null;
        addedpass = null;
        addedemail = null;
        addedwebsite = null;

        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are all appearing in the top node, is you are using treecount with a value of 0 to index the Nodes.  Therefore, t.Nodes[treecount] will always be the first node in the list rather than the newly created node.

I think an easier and more clear method would be to add an entire node:

```
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(nodename);
newNode.Nodes.Add($"Username: {addedname ?? "Empty"}");
newNode.Nodes.Add($"Password: {addedpass ?? "Empty"}");
newNode.Nodes.Add($"Email: {addedemail ?? "Empty"}");
newNode.Nodes.Add($"Website: {addedwebsite ?? "Empty"}");

treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

That way you don't need to be concerned with indexes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Integer to add children to back to zero after refreshing

add the integer outside of the void